# TIdHTTPServer hangs on Free() when placed in DLL

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, indy, httpserver, idhttp

I need to put an instance of `TIdHTTPServer` into DLL for some reasons. It's done like this:

**Interface unit:**

```
unit DLL.Intf;

interface

type
  IServer = interface
    procedure DoSomethingInterfaced();
  end;

implementation

end.
```

**Server's container:**

```
unit Server;

interface

uses
  DLL.Intf,
  IdHTTPServer,
  IdContext,
  IdCustomHTTPServer;

type
  TServer = class(TInterfacedObject, IServer)
  private
    FHTTP: TIdHTTPServer;
    procedure HTTPCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo;
      AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
    procedure DoSomethingInterfaced();
  public
    constructor Create();
    destructor Destroy(); override;
  end;

function GetInstance(): IServer;

implementation

uses
  SysUtils;

var
  Inst: IServer;

function GetInstance(): IServer;
begin
  if not Assigned(Inst) then
    Inst := TServer.Create();

  Result := Inst;
end;

constructor TServer.Create();
begin
  inherited;
  FHTTP := TIdHTTPServer.Create(nil);
  FHTTP.OnCommandGet := HTTPCommandGet;
  FHTTP.Bindings.Add().SetBinding('127.0.0.1', 15340);
  FHTTP.Active := True;
end;

destructor TServer.Destroy();
begin
  FHTTP.Free();
  inherited;
end;

procedure TServer.DoSomethingInterfaced();
begin

end;

procedure TServer.HTTPCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo;
  AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  AResponseInfo.ContentText := '<html><h1>HELLO! ' + IntToStr(Random(100)) + '</h1></html>';
end;

end.
```

DLL exports the `GetInstance()` function:

```
library DLL;

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  Server in 'Server.pas',
  DLL.Intf in 'DLL.Intf.pas';

{$R *.res}

exports
  GetInstance;

begin
end.
```

Server loads and works fine until I exit the main EXE file. The debugger has shown the main thread hangs on `FHTTP.Free();`.

I thought I don't need to worry about the thread synchronization because I use "Build with runtime packages" option for both EXE and DLL projects.

How can I fix this hang?

Comment: What happens if you comment out the FHTTP.Free()?

Comment: @MartinJames When not calling Free(), just getting the memory leak, but no hang.

Comment: Facing the same problem here. Anybody with a solution?

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to set `Active` property of `TIdHTTPServer` to `false` when closing the main form of my application.

I guess the server must stop all its threads and synchronize with the main thread before exiting the message loop.

I'll check another answer as correct if it will explain the mechanics behind.

Comment: Maybe.  You would kinda think that the dtor would set the property to false itself, if it was necessary.  Also, I don't think that, in itself, any Indy servers/clients perform any main-thread synchro.  Still, if this answer works, who cares :)

Comment: @MartinJames I hope Remy Lebeau will explain this later.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe should only be happening if your code were synchronizing with the main thread inside of the `TIdHTTPServer` events, like `OnCommandGet`.  But it is not doing so in the code you showed, so there should be nothing blocking the `TIdHTTPServer` destructor from exiting normally.  Internally, the destructor does set the `Active` property to False, which does wait for any active threads to fully terminate.  Nothing inside of `TIdHTTPServer` syncs with the main thread.   Deactivating `TIdHTTPServer` from the main thread while synchronizing with the main thread would cause a deadlock (so would calling `TThread.Synchronize()` inside a DLL in general if Runtime Packages were disabled, which you say they are not).  So what you describe makes no sense.  You will just have to step through the TIdHTTPServer destructor inside the debugger to find the actual deadlock.

Comment: I prepared a test project in Delphi XE. Can you take a look at this please? https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4736768/HTTPServerDLL.zip Maybe I missed something, but it really hangs on `Free()`. This happens only after visiting http://localhost:15340 in any browser when server is running.